# gridview asp.net c# onrowupdating

Tags: asp.net

My problem is,when i click edit,textbox appears in all columns and i write ehatever i want to update,then i click on update button,the rows gets updated in the database,but on page it shows previous values.Please help

```
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmailID")%>'></asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmailID")%>'></asp:TextBox>

    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Password")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Password")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CurrentLocation">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CurrentLocation")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CurrentLocation")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile No.">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MobileNo")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MobileNo")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Address")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Address")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Gender")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Gender")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="true"/>
```

code behind-

protected void GridView1_Edit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {

```
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox ac = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox a = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2");
        TextBox b = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3");
        TextBox c = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox4");
        TextBox d = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox5");
        TextBox k = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox6");
        TextBox f = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox7");
        TextBox g = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox8");

        ru.EmailID1=ac.Text;
        ru.FirstName1=a.Text;
        ru.LastName1=b.Text;
        ru.Password1=c.Text;
        ru.Location=d.Text;
        ru.MobileNo=k.Text;
        ru.Address=f.Text;
        ru.gender = g.Text;
```

Comment: Please post your code for building the `DataSource` of the `GridView`?

Comment: i have followed # layered approach-

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            
                if (Session["UI"] != null)
                {
                    name = Session["UI"].ToString();

                    viewedituserdetails vd = new viewedituserdetails();
                    DataSet ds = vd.viewuser(name);
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("UserLogin.aspx");
                }
            

        }

Comment: public class viewedituserdetails
    {
            public DataSet viewuser(string name1)
            {
                viewedituserdetails1 v = new viewedituserdetails1();
                DataSet d = v.viewuser1(name1);
                return d;

            }
    }

Comment: public class viewedituserdetails1
    {
        public DataSet viewuser1(string name2)
        {
           // string connectionString = "Data Source=INGNRILPSQL02;Initial Catalog=AHD08_A40;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=a36;Password=a36";
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=DELL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Nikita;Integrated Security=True";

            string queryString = "Select EmailID,FirstName,LastName,Password,CurrentLocation,MobileNo,Address,Gender from PS3_RegistrationUser where UserID='"+name2+"'";

Comment: string queryString = "Select EmailID,FirstName,LastName,Password,CurrentLocation,MobileNo,Address,Gender from PS3_RegistrationUser where UserID='"+name2+"'";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sc);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            // sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.Fill(ds);



            return ds;

Answer (score 0):

You can set the EnableViewState property to True for each TextBox in your gridview. This will ensure that the values you entered in Edit mode are seen after page posts back. Also, you may change Eval to Bind, as Eval is read-only while Bind works both ways.

Comment: i have done EnableViewState property to True but still it is working the same.when i edit the row and then i click on update,then the new values gets update in database but,when i click on edit to update the same row,then it shows me the latest value in database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are not updating the `DataSource` of the `GridView`, thus when you call `DataBind()` on the grid, it is using the data it has in the non-updated data source, thus the "old" values appear.

Instead, once you have successfully saved the changes to the database, then perform the logic of querying the database to build the data source and then re-bind the grid, like this:

```
SaveChangesToDatabase();

GridView1.DataSource = GetDataFromDatabase();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Response.Redirect and insert it after your code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    TextBox ac = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
    TextBox a = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2");
    TextBox b = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3");
    TextBox c = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox4");
    TextBox d = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox5");
    TextBox k = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox6");
    TextBox f = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox7");
    TextBox g = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox8");

    ru.EmailID1=ac.Text;
    ru.FirstName1=a.Text;
    ru.LastName1=b.Text;
    ru.Password1=c.Text;
    ru.Location=d.Text;
    ru.MobileNo=k.Text;
    ru.Address=f.Text;
    ru.gender = g.Text;

    Response.Redirect("currentpage.aspx" + "?urlparam1=" + value1 + "&urlparam2=" + value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
protected void GridViewUser_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var id = e.NewValues["Id"] + string.Empty;
                var login = e.NewValues["Login"] + string.Empty;
                var password = e.NewValues["Password"] + string.Empty;

                Validate(false,login, password);

                var dto = new UserDto();
                dto.Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                dto.Login = (login + string.Empty).Trim();
                dto.Password = password;
                _userBo.Save(dto);
                GridViewUser.EditIndex = -1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Core.Util.Util.ShowPopUpMsg(this, "Erro não esperado: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                FillGrid();
            }


        }
```